# CRLF injection Prevention/URL becomes invalid upon using ESAPI URL encoder

Tags: java, jsp, url, encoding, esapi

If my URL is this:

```
response.sendRedirect(new fucntionone().functiontwo(request,"/x/y.jsp")+"?value=1&name=" + name);
```

Once I encode it, the new JSP fails to display.

Should I just encode the vulnerable parameters (if there is no other way) or use some other encoding for the whole URL.

Comment: I don't even think that URL is RFC 1738 compliant much less RFC 3986!

Comment: In other words, please give us the concrete URL, both the before and after, as well as the code you're using to do the encoding.

Comment: Also, provide enough code that someone can reasonably reproduce the problem.